# SQL Log shipping, moving secondary database files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a secondary database which is sat as a log shipping method for my primary database. Now I want to move the secondary database and I have no access to the primary database. So,could anyone describe the possible ways for moving the secondary database  please?
Also, can I use attach detach for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Since your database is a secondary database a in Log Shipping session, Your database will be either in a `Restoring State` or `Standby Mode`.

You will need to bring your database in an available state to do anything with it. You will need to restore all the outstanding transaction log backups with `WITH NORECOVERY` except the very last one , you will need to restore it with `WITH RECOVERY` option.

something like

```
RESTORE LOG Test_DB 
   FROM DISK = 'D:\Log_Backs\Database_201412041600.trn' 
WITH NORECOVERY;     --<-- norecovery
GO

RESTORE LOG Test_DB 
   FROM DISK = 'D:\Log_Backs\Database_201412041605.trn' 
WITH RECOVERY;     --<-- recovery
GO
```

At this point your secondary database will be in normal/available state, now you can take a backup to move it or detach/attach database, whatever is more convenient.

Comment: I just moved the secondary database and database seems cant map to its' files (mdf/ldf) and it is in Restoring mode for a long time. I used the bellow code and carefully I reviewed it several times!
Alter Database X
  modify file (name= X , filegroup= 'Y.mdf');
Alter Database X
  modify file (name= X , filegroup= 'Y.ldf');